# Windows filename is in an unusual font... how?

Tags: windows, fonts

I downloaded a file, and the filename is not in the standard system font.

Anything added to the filename appears in the system font. If I copy and paste the filename into WordPad, it claims it's Cambria Math bold size 10, although typing in that font doesn't match.

I've never seen this before, and I'm wondering how this is possible?

Comment: Could you first describe how you determined that it is in fact Cambria Math Bold?

Comment: I edited the above to explain better. (I copied/pasted to WordPad.)

Comment: Could you copy/paste the name here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that single font practically never covers all of Unicode; instead the OS or the program may combine multiple fonts in order to render text (perform font substitution/fallback), instead of just drawing boxes for "unknown characters". This is completely automatic and does not imply that the text itself specifies a font. Instead the OS chooses a font.

For example, the whole reason for Cambria Math is to act as the subsitute font when the primary font doesn't have the specialized math symbols. (Similarly, Noto Sans is a large collection of fonts, each dedicated to its own single script.)

Second, among those math symbols, Unicode has a block named [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols), which are meant to have a specific appearance regardless of font. Note that these aren't just standard letters in a different font; they're different Unicode characters entirely and only look the same. I am *guessing* that these characters are exactly what was used in your filename.

For example, I used an online converter (of which there are several) to translate regular ASCII text to these "math" characters:
Math bold:  .
Math bold Fraktur:  .
Math sans:  .
(...or at least I hope that worked, because my phone cannot display them.)

Finally, I suspect that WordPad probably does this font matching on its own, as a legacy from its Windows 98 era (when you needed "Arial (Western)", "Arial (Greek)", "Arial (Baltic)"...), and as a result makes the chosen font visible in the "Font" setting because that's how it had to work back then. This does not mean the *original* text has any font specification at all; it only shows the font that WordPad has chosen for this text.

Comment: Thanks! When I copy your examples above into a filename, they retain their font.

This seems to be the exact answer, although I can't seem to find a way to vote for your answer...

Comment: Figured it out! BTW to your question above, SuperUser won't let me comment. Here's the filename:    .mp4 (It said "online" but I messed it up when I pasted " " into it.)